# Apollo with Angular Quickstart : Unknown error

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, graphql, apollo

I am a complete newbie in web development, and I am completely lost.

I want to develop a web application with a backend developed with Django, and a frontend developed with Angular. I want the interaction between the backend and the frontend to be accomplished with Apollo and GraphQL.

Taking this into account, I started developing a couple of simple models in Django, and doing some queries with the Python package graphene. It seems to be working well, so now I tried to develop a simple Angular application that renders the instances of the Django created models.

And that is where I am stuck. I have downloaded the Angular Quickstart used in the Angular tutorial (https://github.com/angular/quickstart) to start testing Apollo. I have run the following commands in the terminal:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/angular/quickstart.git
$ cd quickstart
$ npm install
```

Furthermore, to install Apollo, I have run the following commands:

```
$ npm install whatwg-fetch apollo-client apollo-angular graphql-tag --save
```

Finally, to run the local server, I typed `$ npm start` in the terminal. And that is where the following error is raised:

```
node_modules/@types/isomorphic-fetch/index.d.ts(8,30): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'fetch'.
```

I am getting mad trying to solve this issue, and I have not found any documentation on this, maybe because I do not have an extensive background on web development.

I am using node v6.10.3, npm v3.10.10 and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Any advice or help to solve the problem would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you have a problem with typings, try installing `@types/whatwg-fetch`.

Answer (score 0):

The release of `@types/isomorphic-fetch` you have installed (one of the deps of `apollo-client`) assumes that you have a declaration of `window.fetch`.

The ~2.3 version of TypeScript has that definition in `dom` library and I think this is why Apollo and `@types/isomorphic-fetch` decided to work this way.

There are two solutions:

- Install `@types/whatwg-fetch` package (or different) or define `fetch` by yourself
- Update TypeScript to 2.3.X (and have `dom` specified in `compilerOptions.lib`